# How to paint on oppisite faces in Texture painting mode?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I need draw on backfaces but I dont know how and possible it or not

Comment: @moonboots Basically, I'm interested in how to draw on backfaces, through objects. I don't have a specific model. Well, how, for example, to draw on the backfaces of a cube?

Comment: by backface of a cube do you mean the inner face or the opposite face?

Comment: @moonboots  I mean opposite face

Comment: In that case my first comment was inaccurate. I'm not sure that it's easily possible, in what case would you want to paint on the opposite face?

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn off Occlude and Backfacte Culling in Option Settings
   [image]
2. Turn off Normal Falloff in Falloff settings
   [image]